# Arch Linux terminal not starting

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, gnome, gnome3, gnome-terminal

I just installed Arch Linux following a video tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMgGUBDxCjo) for the first time. However, when I try starting the GNOME terminal it won't start. It will say Terminal at the top of my screen for a couple of seconds and there will be a loading symbol, but after a couple of seconds they both disappear and no terminal will appear. Because I can't load or start the terminal I can't do anything (I can't even answer the question to register to the Arch Linux forums). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. You should use the Arch documentation to install Arch: youtube guides are either wrong, out-of-date or both. 2. What terminal are you trying to start, and in what Desktop Environment?

Comment: I am using the gnome desktop and am trying to load it's default terminal

Comment: Make sure your [locale is set correctly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale) (see the note in the troubleshooting section).

Comment: How can I edit it without using a terminal?

Comment: You really should be running a more newbie-friendly distro... You can edit files from the TTY using `nano` or `vim`...

Comment: How did you get it to install at all without a console? `CTRL+ALT+FNUM` should get you a console in which you can edit whatever you like regardless of your desktop environment. @jasonwryan may have a point though - Manjaro might be more your speed. Still, don't let that discourage you. You mention the forums - I assume that means you've got a browser running like chrome or firefox or something - likely you can use a browser extension to edit text if necessary. My own terminal preference is for terminology which you can probably get with `pacman -S terminology`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Maybe the question was poorly phrased, but it's a valid question, and shouldn't be down-voted so much. If someone does have an answer, it could just start with “Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and log in”.

Answer (score 53):

I had the same issue after a fresh install of arch.  I checked, double checked and triple checked the locale.gen and even removed every locale except en_US.UTF-8.  I was just about to give up when I checked under settings, Regions & Language and discovered the language was not set even though I had run the command to set it.  After picking english and rebooting it works fine.

Comment: Thank you!
I had also picking english for the Formats, right underneath Language.

Answer (score 36):

Sounds like you messed up your `/etc/locale.gen` file.

If you are english/US, comment out any of the other entries in that file, UNLESS YOU NEED THEM.  They are for other languages.  If you are american you more then likely only need  `en_US.UTF8`.

Edit the `/etc/locale.gen` file and uncomment `en_US.UTF8`.

Comment out any others, unless of course you need them to be able to read.

Then run: `sudo locale-gen`

gnome-terminal should start then.  If not install xterm and run gnome-terminal from it to see what is going on:

- `pacman -S xterm`
- Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, or exit X.
- Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to get back to X.
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and  type `xterm`
- In the xterm window type `gnome-terminal`

Comment: How will I edit the `locale.gen` file? I have vim but that does not open it

Comment: You can use `gedit` but need to run it with root privs, so `alt+F2` to run a command, then `gedit admin:///etc/locale.gen`

Answer (score 4):

Unless you really care about GNOME terminal, the best way is probably to install a [different terminal emulator](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-terminal-emulators/). Pick one you like.

Remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> gets you to the GUI. Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to go to a TTY. Log in, and search the repositories for the terminal you chose. I chose Guake:

```
pacman -Ss guake
```

It should come up with something. For me, it was:

```
community/guake 0.4.4-3
    Drop-down terminal for GNOME
```

Then, take the name and install that package:

```
pacman -S guake
```

You should then be able to launch the application by switching back to GNOME, pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (the Windows key) and typing the name of the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

in your `~/.xinitrc` replace

```
exec gnome-session
```

with

```
exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
```

Source:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203918

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS ANSWER! I've been fighting this issue for the last week. Nothing worked, but this started it up right away.

Comment: This is deprecated now and should be considered an ugly, and unneccesary, hack.

Answer (score 3):

I just meet the same problem here. I googled a lot, and I found a solution.
If u can use `Alt`+`F2`(maybe laptop +`Fn`) , u can do:

1.login as root (use sudo 'ur pwd')

2. `$locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"`

then u should could open terminal succesfully.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers...

Answer (score 1):

For me gnome-terminal opened after running with `dbus-launch gnome-terminal`.

Afterwards I also run `dbus-update-activation-environment --all` and now it starts without a problem but I am not sure if the latter one did anything.

Answer (score 0):

I just fought with this issue for an hour. It turned out that my problem was that `LC_COLLATE` was set to "`C` " (it had an extra space) instead of "`C`" in `/etc/locale.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution :

1. Copy the file /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc to your ~/.xinitrc
2. Add  just after the line "#start some nice programs" : `exec gnome-session`
3. logout and restart `startx`