# How can I boot Arch Linux on VirtualBox straight into Terminal instead of my Gnome desktop?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-terminal

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux that I am running on VirtualBox. However, I believe the problem is [similar to the one in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126789/arch-linux-terminal-not-starting).

My Terminal is not opening (doing the same thing described in that thread), and when I look at `Settings` - `Region & Language`, and see that the `Language` setting is set to `Unspecified [ANSI_X3.4-1968` even though I set it to `en_US.UTF-8` during the initial installation.

When I click on this and try to change it, the box just says `No languages found`. And I cannot open Terminal to try to edit my `/etc/locale.gen` file.

Thus, I would like to boot Arch Linux into the Terminal so that I can change it from there, but I'm unsure of how to do this. How can I fix this?

Comment: Switch to tty: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts; update /etc/locale.gen; reboot

Comment: By "straight into Terminal", do you mean "boot to a virtual console" (the thing you switch to with ctrl-alt-f1), or do you still want the graphical environment, but with a GNOME terminal starting automatically?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I believe he can't open his terminal in the DE since he has an issue with his locale.gen (as per the answer he linked to).  He just needs to switch to a tty and update it, and then he can boot back into his DE and load his terminal without issue.  I don't think he wants a terminal starting automatically, but I could be mistaken

Comment: @bgregs I can confirm that en_US.UTF-8 is uncommented, and I ran `sudo locale-gen`, and reboot the system, but when I go to the Settings within Gnome the `Language` still says `Unspecified [ANSI_X3.4-1964` and won't allow me to change it.

Comment: Did you add LANG=en_US.UTF-8 to locale.conf?  What does running locale -a give you?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was disable the display manager in the terminal by (assuming it is correct you're using Gnome):

```
systemctl disable gdm.service
reboot
```

That did work for me, and if not, try also stopping the process as well

```
systemctl stop gdm.service
```

and reboot again. This would mean you still have Gnome running but you're just interacting with just command lines only and no desktop environment (you can always re-enable it by just swapping `disable` for `enable` and then `reboot` again).

(I only just installed Arch Linux yesterday so if I'm wrong, please do forgive me :P.)

I also just realised that you can't boot the terminal. I also ran into this problem. I believe I hadn't completed a step properly which was setting my language incorrectly (I don't know how I messed that up :) ) but using the desktop environment, I just went into the settings and went to `region & language` and changed my language to English, that then fixed my problem and was able to boot the terminal. There's a potential you may also have a problem with the format which is just underneath language, so try fixing that too.

Good Luck